# Internet connection listener not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, ethernet

I'm trying to create an Internet connection listener. But not working. I'm not getting any mistakes.I think the NetworkStateChangeReceiver does not work at all. Because Log.e does not appear in logcat. I'm new to Android and it's complicated for me.

**Android manifest**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NetworkStateChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.gdm.retailalfageek.NetworkAvailable" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**NetworkStateChangeReceiver.java**

```
public class NetworkStateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION = "com.gdm.retailalfageek.NetworkAvailable";
public static final String IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE = "isNetworkAvailable";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent networkStateIntent = new Intent(NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    networkStateIntent.putExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE,  getConnectionType(context));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(networkStateIntent);
    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
}

@IntRange(from = 0, to = 2)
public static int getConnectionType(Context context) {
    int result = 0; // Returns connection type. 0: none; 1: mobile data; 2: wifi
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
            Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
                    result = 2;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
                // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
                    result = 2;
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    Log.e("Network Available ", "On receive called");
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}}
```

**Application class**

```
     @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("isNetworkAvailable");
    registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChangeReceiver(), filter);

  }
```

Comment: Try using ```Log.d``` instead, and running in Debug mode. That should help with debugging/figuring out where the problem lies. Could you be a bit more specific about the issue? Do you know whether the receiver is running at all or not?

Comment: I try Log.d but now work. I think never working. (Sorry bad english, i use translate)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the code given below help you.

1. Register a BroadcastReceiver in Manifest.file

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" > 
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Set internet permissions in Manifest

   ```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```
3. Implement receiving class.

   ```
       public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // This will execute upon receiving event
       }
       }
   ```